# keep_lazy for translation messages sent through Django API

Tags: django, translation

I'm working on translation (French to German) of some messages my app send  through Django Api. My problem was that translation worked only if i put LANGUAGE_CODE="de-de".
So i thought was a problem with lazy translation.
I found keep_lazy() decorator but, being really a baby web dev, i can't find the way to incorporate keep_lazy() on my existing decorator. Here is my py file sending message through api request (create document here) :

```
    @method_decorator(
    reponse_toast_decorator(Toast(message=gettext("Votre nouveau document a été créé.")),
    data_field_name="document"),
    name="create",
)
```

Here is my function from utils :

```
def reponse_toast_decorator(toast=None, data_field_name=""):

    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)

            if not isinstance(toast, Toast):
                raise ValueError("L'argument 'toast' doit être une instance de la classe Toast")

            if isinstance(response, Response):

                if response.status_code == status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT:
                    response.status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK

                if response.data is None:
                    response.data = {}

                if not data_field_name:
                    response.data.update({"toast": toast.data})
                    return response

                response.data = {data_field_name: response.data, "toast": toast.data}

            return response

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Being a baby web dev, i can't find the way to incorporate

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, assisted by my lead. We had to submit gettext() to self.message to link to message string from decorator's call :

```
def reponse_toast_decorator(toast=None, data_field_name=""):
"""Décorateur permettant de modifier la response d'une vue"""
def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        response = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if not isinstance(toast, Toast):
            raise ValueError("L'argument 'toast' doit être une instance de la classe Toast")

        if isinstance(response, Response):
            if response.status_code == status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT:
                response.status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK

            if response.data is None:
                response.data = {}

            if not data_field_name:
                response.data.update({"toast": toast.data})
                return response

            response.data = {data_field_name: response.data, "toast": toast.data}

        return response

    return wrapper

return decorator

class Toast:
def __init__(self, message, titre="", delai=2000, statut="succes", langue="", erreur=""):
    self.message = message
    self.statut = statut
    self.titre = titre
    self.langue = langue
    self.erreur = erreur
    self.delai = delai

@property
def data(self):
    """
    Ne pas oublier d'ajouter ici le gettext sur la variable 'message' pour la traduction
    """
    cur_langue = get_language() # Garnissage de la langue en cours pour être récupérée par le Front
    self.langue = cur_langue[0:2].upper()  # Formatage pour le Front
    return {
        "statut": self.statut,
        "message": gettext(self.message),
        "titre": self.titre,
        "langue": self.langue,
        "erreur": self.erreur,
        "delai": self.delai,
    }
```